# Duda sobre procedimiento almacenado que actualiza datos

Tags: sql-server

estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado que me actualize lo datos , al momento de compilarlo me arroa este error "Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'SET'".

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Arriendo_Marcas_U
 @Nombre_Marca VARCHAR(25),
@cMarca SMALLINT
AS
DECLARE @salida nvarchar(30),

-- Validación Mayuscula
SET @Nombre_Marca = UPPER(@Nombre_Marca)
IF NOT exists (
SELECT cMarca
FROM dbo.Arriendo_Marcas
WHERE Nombre_Marca LIKE @Nombre_Marca
)
BEGIN
  -- Actualizar registro
  UPDATE Arriendo_Marcas 
  SET Nombre_Marca=@Nombre_Marca WHERE cMarca=@cMarca

  -- generar mensaje de salida
  SET @salida = 'Registro Actualizado: ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), SCOPE_IDENTITY())
END
  ELSE
-- generar mensaje de salida
SET @salida = 'Registro ya existe'
```

Comment: elimina la coma que esta después de declarar la variable @salida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu inconveniente se encuentra en la declaración de la variable, se te está escapando una ",".

```
DECLARE @salida nvarchar(30), -- Aquí!!
```

Eliminala y prueba. Saludos.